# Python: numpy shape confusion

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
>>> type(myArray1)
Out[14]: numpy.ndarray

>>> myArray1.shape
Out[13]: (500,)
```

I have another array:

```
>>> type(myArray2)
Out[14]: numpy.ndarray

>>> myArray2.shape
Out[13]: (500,1)
```

( 1 ) What is the difference between (500,) and (500,1) ?

( 2 ) How do I change (500,) to (500,1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) The difference between (500,) and (500,1) is that the first is the shape of a one-dimensional array, while the second is the shape of a 2-dimensional array whose 2nd dimension has length 1. This may be confusing at first since other languages don't make that distinction.

(2) You can use np.reshape to do that: 
`myArray1.reshape(-1,1)`. 
You can also add a dimension to your array using np.expand_dims: `np.expand_dims(myArray1, axis = 1)`.

Comment: Also note that a very common idiom to do the same thing as `reshape(-1, 1)` is `my_array[:, None]` or a bit more readably `my_array[:, np.newaxis]`.

Answer (score 5):

The difference between (500,) and (500,1) is the number of dimension (the first one is "totally flat").
You can try it by yourself:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([i for i in range(250)])
arr.shape
# (250,)
new_arr = np.array([i for i in range(250)], ndmin=2).T
new_arr.shape
# (250, 1)
# You can also reshape it directly:
arr.shape = (250, 1)
# And look the result:
arr
# array([[  0],
#   [  1],
#   [  2],
#   [  3],
#   [  4],
#   (...)
```

Try also to reverse the shape, like (1, 500) instead of (500, 1).